# $\iint y^2 dxdy$ over circular region

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose I want to calculate $$\iint y^2 dxdy$$ over region outside $$C_1=x^2 + y^2 = ax$$ and inside $$C_2=x^2 + y^2 = 2ax$$. How can we perform this integral?
I approached this problem using polar coordinates.Polar equation of $C_1$ would be $$r=a\cos(\theta)$$ and for $C_2$ would be $$r=2a\cos(\theta)$$
and our region should be  $$r=2a\cos(\theta)- a\cos(\theta) = a\cos(\theta)$$ 
So , our integral becomes
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{a\cos(\theta)}r^3 sin^2(\theta)drd\theta$$
but this is giving me $a^4\pi / 128$ which seems to be wrong answer. Help? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: the lower limit of r is $a \cos\theta$ the upper limit is $2a\cos\theta$  You can't just find the difference before you integrate.

Comment: @DougM How can I be sure that lower limit should be $a\cos(\theta)$ and not 0 ?

Comment: Outside C1 inside C2.  C1 makes one limit, C2 is the other.  Lower limit of 0 suggests inside one curve.

Comment: The upper bound of the outer integral doesn’t look right to me, either. (Or, you need to double the result.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ so that 
$$
C_1:\,r=a\cos\theta\qquad C_2:\,r=2a\cos\theta\qquad\theta\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]
$$
[image]

So the integral becomes
\begin{align}
\iint_{C_2\setminus C_1} y^2\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{a\cos\theta}^{2a\cos\theta}r^3\sin^2\theta\,\mathrm d r\,\mathrm d \theta\\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2\theta\frac{1}{4}\,\left(r^4\Big|_{a\cos\theta}^{2a\cos\theta}\right)\,\mathrm d \theta\\
&=\frac{15a^4}{4}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2\theta\cos^4\theta\,\mathrm d \theta=\frac{15a^4}{4}\cdot\frac{\pi}{16}
\end{align}